# Prevent line breaks in grid columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I training by create the Google Homepage and I have an issue on the footer which has a line break in 2 columns.

[image: My current result]

```css
#footer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px,1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "pub entreprise propos comment neutre infos confidentialite conditions parametres";
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
```

```html
 <div id="footer">
       <a href="#" id="pub">Publicité</a>
       <a href="#" id="entreprise">Entreprise</a>
       <a href="#" id="propos">A propos</a>
       <a href="#" id="comment">Comment fonctionne la recherche Google ?</a>
       <a href="#" id="neutre">Neutre en carbone depuis 2007</a>
       <a href="#" id="infos">Infos consommateurs</a>
       <a href="#" id="confidentialite">Confidentialité</a>
       <a href="#" id="conditions">Conditions</a>
       <a href="#" id="parametres">Paramètres</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `white-space : nowrap` and not use `grid-template-columns` to enforce fitting of text within fraction of screen. But also you will have to take care of the responsive behaviour when width decreases. If that's not the requirement then this shall work. Maybe on shrinking of screen use a media query to have 2 rows instead of just one.

```css
#footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "pub entreprise propos comment neutre infos confidentialite conditions parametres";
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <a href="#" id="pub">Publicité</a>
  <a href="#" id="entreprise">Entreprise</a>
  <a href="#" id="propos">A propos</a>
  <a href="#" id="comment">Comment fonctionne la recherche Google ?</a>
  <a href="#" id="neutre">Neutre en carbone depuis 2007</a>
  <a href="#" id="infos">Infos consommateurs</a>
  <a href="#" id="confidentialite">Confidentialité</a>
  <a href="#" id="conditions">Conditions</a>
  <a href="#" id="parametres">Paramètres</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to note that your `grid-template-areas` definition is not mapped to the grid items. This is because you haven't defined the `grid-area` property for each item.

The wrapping problem can be solved with `white-space: nowrap`.

```css
#footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "pub entreprise propos comment neutre infos confidentialite conditions parametres";
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

#pub              { grid-area: pub; }
#entreprise       { grid-area: entreprise; }
#propos           { grid-area: propos; }
#comment          { grid-area: comment; }
#neutre           { grid-area: neutre; }
#infos            { grid-area: infos; }
#confidentialite  { grid-area: confidentialite; }
#conditions       { grid-area: conditions; }
#parametres       { grid-area: parametres; }

#footer > a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 25px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <a href="#" id="pub">Publicité</a>
  <a href="#" id="entreprise">Entreprise</a>
  <a href="#" id="propos">A propos</a>
  <a href="#" id="comment">Comment fonctionne la recherche Google ?</a>
  <a href="#" id="neutre">Neutre en carbone depuis 2007</a>
  <a href="#" id="infos">Infos consommateurs</a>
  <a href="#" id="confidentialite">Confidentialité</a>
  <a href="#" id="conditions">Conditions</a>
  <a href="#" id="parametres">Paramètres</a>
</div>
```